# How to draw Kepler Poinsot Polyhedra in tikz?

Tags: tikz-pgf

How to draw Kepler Poinsot Polyhedra in tikz?

[image]

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it does not show effort of what has been tried so far.

Comment: You can draw manually using https://www.mathcha.io/editor